# How to install rpm package from Puppet (Failed dependencies)

Tags: apache, puppet, rpm, centos7, perl-module

I am trying to install **perl-Apache-DBI** on Centos7 with Puppet (puppetserver version: 2.7.2, puppet: 4.8.1).

Manually, I would just download the rpm package from this [page](https://centos.pkgs.org/7/epmel-x86_64/perl-Apache-DBI-1.12-1.el7.noarch.rpm.html) and install it with yum (`yum install perl-Apache-DBI-1.12-1.el7.noarch.rpm`).

In Puppet I tried:

```
package { perl-Apache-DBI:
  provider => 'rpm',
  ensure => installed,
  source => "https://harbottle.gitlab.io/epmel/7/x86_64//perl-Apache-DBI-1.12-1.el7.noarch.rpm",
}
```

And have error:

> Error: Execution of '/bin/rpm -i https://harbottle.gitlab.io/epmel/7/x86_64//perl-Apache-DBI-1.12-1.el7.noarch.rpm' returned 1:
>   warning: /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.SKxxuP: Header V4 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID 540ecf1b: NOKEY
>   error: Failed dependencies:
>           perl(Digest::SHA1) >= 2.01 is needed by perl-Apache-DBI-1.12-1.el7.noarch
>           perl(Test::Simple) is needed by perl-Apache-DBI-1.12-1.el7.noarch

Also, I tried to use the `yum` provider in the package resource, but it does not work either.

Comment: `source` does not work with the `yum` provider, so you cannot do that. If you want to use the `rpm` provider, then you need to manually install of the dependencies too. The best path for you is probably to subscribe to a repo with that package and then install with yum.

Comment: Thank you, Matt. I did as you said, added rpm to own repo and use "yum" provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best path for me is probably to subscribe to a repo with that package and then install with yum.

Answer (score 2):

try downloading from here:

```
package { perl-Apache-DBI:
    provider => 'rpm',
    install_options => ['-q'],
    ensure => installed,
    source => "http://search.cpan.org/dist/Apache-DBI",
}
```

I've change the url source

Comment: Sorry, have error:
Error: Execution of '/bin/rpm -i -qi http://search.cpan.org/dist/Apache-DBI/' returned 1: package http://search.cpan.org/dist/Apache-DBI/ is not installed

Comment: First try only with - q additional installed_options. If doesn't Try without the additional line install_options at all, also I deleted the las / from the url.

Comment: `-q` is the option to query information about an installed package. How would that help him at all?